# What is the difference between deploying application with Heroku or Personal VPS

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment, vps

I am trying to deploy my application but did not know which is the best:

Using Heroku or Using a VPS ?

Regards;

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume by VPS you mean AWS.

**Heroku runs on AWS**.

What Heroku does is it makes your deployment easier for you. You don't have to install dependencies, you don't have to run load balancers, you don't have to do anything more than a 
'git push'. This is good if all you want to do is check how your code runs during development.

However when going deploying your code for production, it would be better if you use a VPS service like AWS. It gives you much more control over the environment in which your code runs and will be easier to add tweaks.